# change rails environment from within ruby file then change back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a test-automation app that runs tests against user params against a rails app.

The tests execution in the Ruby app looks like this:

```
config = RSpec.configuration
json_formatter = RSpec::Core::Formatters::JsonFormatter.new(config.out)
reporter =  RSpec::Core::Reporter.new(json_formatter)
config.instance_variable_set(:@reporter, reporter)

RSpec::Core::Runner.run(["#{Rails.root}/spec/features/example_spec.rb"])

puts json_formatter.output_hash
```

This works great but runs in the current environment, i.e. `development`.

I want to change the Rails environment so that this code is executed in the `test` environment and then change it back.

Does anyone know how to do this?

thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the environment for a single (or set of) commands like this in unix-like environments:

```
RAILS_ENV=testing bundle exec rspec
```

or whatever you need to execute. You could, for example, define a custom rake task that contains your spec-running logic and call that as I outlined above.

Using this concept and taking it a step further, you could execute shell commands directly from Ruby and have a custom environment variable set for only this command. In this shell commands you could execute arbitrary Ruby code (e.g. via `ruby -e ...`) or even call another Ruby file that properly initializes whatever you need within your desired environment.

I think it would be really bad practice to try to change the current environment from within your code, even if it is somehow possible. I would personally stick with a custom, dedicated, rake task which I can call from my command line with whatever environment I need.